# THREEJS After using the subdivision modifier on a sphere the shape is no longer solid, how can I make it back into a solid object?

Tags: three.js

I am creating a cylinder and then using the subdivision modifier to round the edges. After I apply this the shape is no longer solid. Could anyone point me in the right direction for how to make it a solid color again. I tried merging the vertices but that didn't seem to do anything. Thanks!

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.4, 0.4, .5, 100);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xeef007, shading: THREE.SmoothShading} );
var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier( .5 );
geometry.mergeVertices();

modifier.modify( geometry );
var cyl = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
minifig.add( cyl );
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDRaM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "solid" you mean not flat-shaded. Recompute the normals:

```
modifier.modify( geometry ); 
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```